# How to connect old Atari style joystick to bluetooth PCB?

Tags: pcb, bluetooth

I have an old Atari style joystick, and a dismantled modern bluetooth gamepad that I've taken the PCB out of. I'm wondering if it's possible to connect the 2 so that the PCB recognises when the joystick has been moved/button pressed, therefore creating a 'bluetooth Atari joystick', of sorts.

The modern gamepad appears to use rubber underneath it's buttons which I guess makes a circuit when it touches the black 'pads' on the PCB. I'm very new to all this so please excuse the terminology. I'm not sure how to replicate this with my 'merged' joystick as it won't be using the rubber bits.

If I can get power to the Atari joystick, would it be enough to solder the correct pins (from the 9pin connector) to the corresponding 'pads' on the PCB? If I then push the joystick Up for instance, would that send a signal through to the Up pad?

I've got images below showing a PCB from a similar gamepad, and the Atari joystick connecter showing the pins. Is this even possible or am I way off? thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why don't you try it? What have you got to lose?

Comment: That schematic does not look like it has anything to do with that controller.....

Comment: Trevor_G correct it's from the Atari connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Atari plug uses a single common pin for all the switches (pin 8), and then separate pins for each switch.

You need to trace out your PCB to see if it's the same.  If not, then you'd need a bunch of interfacing logic and it's a lot more complicated.

If you're in luck and all the pads on the PCB share a common line, then you've just got the very fiddly job of soldering in the wires at the right points.

Comment: Thanks Simon. So those black discs on the PCB, I'm not sure what their correct name is, but I can solder wire onto those and that is okay from a circuit point of view? I'm just asking as the gamepad seems to just push a bit of rubber onto them and for whatever reason that makes the circuit.

Comment: The black discs will actually be **two** tracks close to each other.  Pressing the conductive rubber onto them makes a connection between the two.  So you need to be very careful what you are soldering.

Comment: That black stuff will be hard to solder to. the chip pins will be easier to solder to, but they are very small. the tracks on the circuit board can be soldered if you scrape the green solder-mask back, but they are also very small, and fragile.

Comment: I'm wondering now if this thing could be _physically_ engineered, rather than getting into potentially breaking the PCB with solder. Like the inside of the Atari stick just pushes metal plates down to make the circuit, if I could stuff the PCB in there somehow and get it the stick to push the conductive rubber down ontto the PCB.. probably won't work but I'll check it out. Thanks again.